# Using Monte Carlo for portfolio optimisation but must satisfy constraints

Tags: python, optimization, montecarlo, quantitative-finance, portfolio

I have a problem trying to find portfolio weights and optimise them while satisfying constraints.
I require some help on designing a code that would allow me to simulate multiple arrays of weights while satisfying a range of constraints, please see example below for an explanation:

Problem - simulate various weights while satisfying constraints:

Instruments = ['Fixed Income', 'Equity 1', 'Equity 2', 'Multi-Asset', 'Cash']

Constraints:

1. each weight between 0.1 and 0.4
2. cash = 0.05
3. Equity 1 less than 0.3

At the moment I have code:

```
import numpy as np:

instruments = ['Fixed Income', 'Equity 1', 'Equity 2', 'Multi-Asset', 'Cash']

weights = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4, len(instruments)) # random number generation
weights = weights / weights.sum() # normalise weights
# I have done test runs, and normalised weights always fit the constraints

if weights[-1] > 0.03:
   excess = weights[-1] - 0.03
   # distribute excess weights equally
   weights[:-1] = weights[:-1] + excess / (len(weights) - 1)
```

and I'm stuck, I also realised that when I distribute the excess weights I have effectively broken my constraint.

Is there anyway to do it? and I have to do it via monte-carlo

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: what exactly is Monte Carlo about the above set-up? I see no replications/simulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
import numpy as np
N = 1000000
instruments = ['Fixed Income', 'Equity 1', 'Equity 2', 'Multi-Asset', 'Cash']

# each row is set of weights in order of instruments above
weights = np.zeros(shape=(N, len(instruments)))

weights[:, -1] = 0.05
weights[:, 1] = np.random.uniform(0, 0.3, N)

cols = (0, 2, 3)

# fill columns with random numbers
for col in cols[0:-1]:
    w_remaining = 1 - np.sum(weights, axis=1)
    weights[:, col] = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.4, N)

# the last column is constrained for normalization
weights[:, cols[-1]] = 1 - np.sum(weights, axis=1)

# select only rows that meet condition:
cond1 = np.all(0.1 <= weights[:, cols], axis=1)
cond2 = np.all(weights[:, cols] <= 0.4, axis=1)
valid_rows = cond1*cond2

weights = weights[valid_rows, :]

# verify sum of weights == 1:
np.testing.assert_allclose(np.sum(weights, axis=1), 1)
```

This solution is performant, but discards generated examples that don't satisfy the constraints.

Comment: I don't believe this is quite mathematically sound.  You are choosing the weight for column[1] first, then apportioning the rest.  It is close because the sum of the expected values is close to the total weight, but not quite.

Comment: @AirSquid I don't know what you find unsound.  There is not a unique method for satisfying the constraints provided; this is one way to do it.   I have included a normalization assertion test for all simulated weights

Comment: OK.  Fair enough.  It's an interesting problem and after a tiny bit of research, can't find poke too many holes or find alternative approach.  As long as we realize that at the end of the day, the distributions for the individual weights will not be uniform [and likely can't be made to be in this case] because of the jointedness of the problem

Comment: @anon01, thanks for your solution I found it very helpful, I was just wondering if you may also be able to help me on a slighlty trickier task, what if I have an additional constraints where Equity Asset needs to be < 0.5, i.e. sum of Equity 1 and Equity 2 needs to be < 0.5?

Comment: @DazzW feel free to create a new question and ping me with a comment

Answer (score 0):

In my PoV using montecarlo simulation for portfolio optimization is very inefficient due to the problem is very hard when you increase the number of assets even if you use sobol sequence.

On the other, hand the majority of portfolio optimization problems are quadratic or linear programming problems, so you can use cvxpy to solve it but it takes time to model each problem. Finally, you can try Riskfolio-Lib a library  based on cvxpy that simplify the implementation of portfolio optimization models, even have a format to implement asset classes constraints like you are trying to implement.

You can check the first example in this link: https://riskfolio-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html